# How to get SQL error code java.rmi.RemoteException

Tags: java, mysql, ejb, rmi

i am very new to EJB. In our code we are performing ejb.remove() to delete a record in database. as that record has some forein key relation with other table  I am getting a exception

> Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: [USLR1-DEV-AP2D]The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK__BPRelationship_CardReg". The conflict occurred in
>   database "MobileRecharge", table "dbo.BillPaymentRelationships".
>           at com.pramati.ejb.runtime.CMRPersistenceManager.remove(CMRPersistenceManager.java:973)
>           at com.pramati.ejb.runtime.CMP20EntityRelationshipCIBase._pramati_impl_remove(CMP20EntityRelationshipCIBase.java:1051)
>           ... 76 more
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [USLR1-DEV-AP2D]The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK__BPRelationship_CardReg". The conflict occurred in d
>   atabase "MobileRecharge", table "dbo.BillPaymentRelationships".

I want to show a specific message in the UI based on the sqlError code. here I can catch the java.rmi.RemoteException but couldn't find a way to get SQL error code. Please help. 
I tried to print remoteException.detail and getcause() both are coming as null.
Not sure but when I print the stack trace I can see caused by ejbExcaption and casued by SQLException. please help me.

Comment: Maybe you wanna see this link: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-ejbexcept/

Comment: You could try `getCause()` which gives you the SQLException, and then `getErrorCode()`.

Comment: @Hatjhie thanks for the link it has some valid information but still I could not get the soultion.

Comment: @Thilo thnaks for the reply..I thought that should work.before posting my question here i tried that but it is giving null for the  getCause().

Comment: According to the link above, you can get the SQLException and once you get the SQLException, you can get the error codes based on this link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlexception.html